# How to store date from Picker to Core Data?

Tags: swift, core-data, dateformatter

I'd like to ask for an explanation why `Dateformatter` adds time and -1 day that I don't want. I need to save the date only in the format `"yyyy-MM-dd"` in the `Date` type field in Core Data

```
let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let formattedDate = dateFormat.string(from: myDatePicker.date)
let date = dateFormat.date(from: formattedDate)
    
print(formattedDate)
print(date!)
```

> 2023-10-08.
> 2023-10-07 22:00:00 +0000

I need to store only 2023-10-08

Comment: Your time zone is UTC+0200. `2023-10-07 22:00:00 +0000` and `2023-10-08 00:00:00 +0200` are the same point in time, unless you really need UTC then set the time zone of the formatter accordingly. If the date picker shows the date only then the entire conversion back and forth is pointless anyway.

Comment: When I add print(myDatePicker.date) - result 
`2023-10-08

2023-10-07 22:00:00 +0000

2023-10-08 10:36:56 +0000`

I need only 2023-10-08 or 2023-10-08 00:00:00 +0000

Comment: Then use [startOfDay(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293783-startofday) of Calendar. It strips the time portion.

Comment: @vadian `startOfDay(for:)` doesn't strip the time portion. It sets the time to the start of the given day (midnight in most cases) based on the Calendar's timezone.